# sql ошибка добавления записи

Tags: sql, node.js

node js

```
function registration(req,res){
   let body = '';
   req.on('data',chunk =>{
   body += chunk.toString();
   let info_post = parse(body);
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host: 'localhost',
   user: 'root',
   database: 'login',
   password: ''
});
let sql = `INSERT INTO user_info (login, password, email) VALUES (${info_post.login} , ${info_post.password}, ${info_post.email})`;
console.log(sql)
connection.connect(function(err){
   if(err)return console.error("Ошибка: " + err.message);
})
connection.query(sql, function(err, results) {
   if(err) console.log(err);
});     
connection.end(function(err) {
      if (err) {
           return console.log("Ошибка: " + err.message);
         }
      console.log("Подключение с БД закрыто");
   });  
});
```

при добавлении 3 параметра возникает ошибка:

```
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlState: '42000',
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@eer)' at line 1"
```

как это исправить? В бд стоит email - varchar

Comment: `console.log(sql)` что выводит?

Comment: INSERT INTO user_info (login, password, email) VALUES (1213dds , asdad, sdadsa), я ничего не менял, и у меня появилась еще 1 ошибка, но уже с логином...

Comment: code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
  errno: 1054,
  sqlState: '42S22',
  sqlMessage: "Unknown column '1213dds' in 'field list'"

Comment: Строковые литералы следует обрамлять одинарными кавычками. Должно быть: `INSERT INTO user_info (login, password, email) VALUES ('1213dds' , 'asdad', 'sdadsa')`

Comment: Спасибо вам, бился часа 2, и не мог понять...

Comment: Ну явно же сообщение об ошибке говорит, что `1213dds` воспринимается как имя поля. А чем отличается имя поля от строкового литерала? отсутствием кавычек вокруг...

Comment: Не надо так делать: вставлять строки непосредственно  в формируемый запрос (SQL injection не дремлет)! Пользуйтесь параметрами запроса (позиционные или именованные, в зависимости от того, что поддерживается либой/базой).